# Adding two number isn't working on heroku

Tags: python, heroku

Why this code is not running on heroku? (Internal server error)

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = a + b
    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Logs:

Starting process with command `python app.py`
     a = 1
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
File "app.py", line 8

This code is working (Python hello world from heroku guides)

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Comment: i'd say you are supposed to return a string ? also, it could be an issue with your indenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like that not your code is being executed.  After all your line was `a = 10` and the log file complains about a line stating `a = 1`.

Or maybe there's a strange (invisible?) character between the `1` and the `0`.

I'd propose to change that value from `10` to `42` for testing and see in what way the error log message changes.